# Cannot test SPFX webparts on my SharePoint tenancy

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I am using the SPFX and I have created my webpart using SPFX and gulp serve is running on my development machine but when I try and test the web part on my tenancy I get this error message :

> Your web part will not appear in the toolbox. Please make sure "gulp
>   serve" is running in a web part project. Please refresh the page once
>   "gulp serve" is running.

What is wrong ?

---

This is the complete output from debugger :-

```
> SCRIPT5022: SyntaxError workbench.aspx (1370,159) SCRIPT5022:
> SyntaxError workbench.aspx (1370,383) Address not found for module
> name: https://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js. Using it as absolute
> URL. sp-loader_en-us_4ec28636b0f9b465bd02537852aebf16.js (61,16921)
> Address not found for module name:
> https://prod.msocdn.com/16.00.1612.006/en-US/JSC/CoreMinShellG2BundleA.js.
> Using it as absolute URL.
> sp-loader_en-us_4ec28636b0f9b465bd02537852aebf16.js (61,16921) Address
> not found for module name: http://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js.
> Using it as absolute URL.
> sp-loader_en-us_4ec28636b0f9b465bd02537852aebf16.js (61,16921)
> SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by
> http://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js workbench.aspx SEC7111: HTTPS
> security is compromised by http://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js
> workbench.aspx Failed to load debug manifests: Error: Error loading
> debug manifest script. (Error) Ensure loading unsafe scripts is
> allowed.
> sp-webpart-workbench_en-us_39ef50033945fc049b9666f1cf113ad0.js
> (47,1232) SCRIPT5022: SyntaxError workbench.aspx (1353,318)
> SCRIPT5022: SyntaxError SuiteServiceProxy.aspx (1370,159) SCRIPT5022:
> SyntaxError SuiteServiceProxy.aspx (1370,383) HTTP401: DENIED - The
> requested resource requires user authentication. GET -
> https://portal.office.com/SuiteServiceProxy.aspx?upn=pricen%40njpenterprises.com&suiteServiceReturnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fnjpenterprises.sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2Fdev%2Fspfx%2F_layouts%2F15%2Fworkbench.aspx&returnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fnjpenterprises.sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2Fdev%2Fspfx%2F_layouts%2F15%2Fworkbench.aspx&Silent=1
> HTTP401: DENIED - The requested resource requires user authentication.
> GET -
> https://portal.office.com/SuiteServiceProxy.aspx?upn=pricen%40njpenterprises.com&suiteServiceReturnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fnjpenterprises.sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2Fdev%2Fspfx%2F_layouts%2F15%2Fworkbench.aspx&returnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fnjpenterprises.sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2Fdev%2Fspfx%2F_layouts%2F15%2Fworkbench.aspx&Silent=1
> HTTP401: DENIED - The requested resource requires user authentication.
> GET -
> https://portal.office.com/SuiteServiceProxy.aspx?upn=pricen%40njpenterprises.com&suiteServiceReturnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fnjpenterprises.sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2Fdev%2Fspfx%2F_layouts%2F15%2Fworkbench.aspx&returnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fnjpenterprises.sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2Fdev%2Fspfx%2F_layouts%2F15%2Fworkbench.aspx&Silent=1
> SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by
> ms-appx-web://microsoft.microsoftedge/assets/errorpages/forbidframingedge.htm SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by
> ms-appx-web://microsoft.microsoftedge/Assets/ErrorPages/httpErrorPagesScripts.js
> SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by
> ms-appx-web://microsoft.microsoftedge/assets/errorpages/ErrorPageStyles.css
> HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the
> requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier). GET -
> https://clientlog.portal.office.com/l.l/?d={m:[{t:408369,l:1,ct:1485861571727,a:["O365SuiteService%252Fapi%252FAppLauncherCustomization%252FUser%252FAppsCustomizationDataTEST"]},{t:171063,l:1,ct:1485861564314,a:["P1","5098","PL","9125","CM1","8985","CM2","8986","C1","9750","C2","9767","M_C","1","M_L","Mouse","SC1","9213","RC1","9439","RC2","9523","R1","9807","M2","9816","PR","9912","R2","9914","S1","10636","D1","10665","I1","10718","S2","10729","I2","13502","D2","14008","G1","14014","G2","14020","M3","14097","I1","16302","I2","19227"]},{t:175272,l:1,ct:1485861583752,a:["https%253A%252F%252Fportal.office.com%252FSuiteServiceProxy.aspx%253Fupn%253Dpricen%252540njpenterprises.com%2526suiteServiceReturnUrl%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fnjpenterprises.sharepoint.com%25252Fsites%25252Fdev%25252Fspfx%25252F_layouts%25252F15%25252Fworkbench.aspx%2526returnUrl%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fnjpenterprises.sharepoint.com%25252Fsites%25252Fdev%25252Fspfx%25252F_layouts%25252F15%25252Fworkbench.aspx"]},{t:421422,l:6,ct:1485861583763,a:["Cannot%2520access%2520https%253A%252F%252Fportal.office.com%252FSuiteServiceProxy.aspx%253Fupn%253Dpricen%252540njpenterprises.com%2526suiteServiceReturnUrl%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fnjpenterprises.sharepoint.com%25252Fsites%25252Fdev%25252Fspfx%25252F_layouts%25252F15%25252Fworkbench.aspx%2526returnUrl%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fnjpenterprises.sharepoint.com%25252Fsites%25252Fdev%25252Fspfx%25252F_layouts%25252F15%25252Fworkbench.aspx"]},{t:410681,l:4,ct:1485861583765,a:["https%253A%252F%252Fportal.office.com%252Fapi%252Fmyapps%252FGetAllApps","GET"]},{t:421432,l:1,ct:1485861583891,a:["0"]},{t:175261,l:1,ct:1485861598529,a:["dd677c9b-d582-4b9b-b380-45349acac10e"]}],a:["s","Sharepoint","shpid","1485861564314","shsid","af21b00a-be43-441e-a6b2-02828b189b84","u","3b756550-4641-468c-9e77-bd03f923f959","t","4e7056d6-0830-41be-a136-93b24c588169","p","10037FFE8190ABEB","c","false","sid","b7a308bf-338a-4061-a7fb-c71931e07a34"]}&cb=1485861628532
> HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the
> requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier). GET -
> https://clientlog.portal.office.com/l.l/?d={m:[{t:408369,l:1,ct:1485861571727,a:["O365SuiteService%252Fapi%252FAppLauncherCustomization%252FUser%252FAppsCustomizationDataTEST"]},{t:171063,l:1,ct:1485861564314,a:["P1","5098","PL","9125","CM1","8985","CM2","8986","C1","9750","C2","9767","M_C","1","M_L","Mouse","SC1","9213","RC1","9439","RC2","9523","R1","9807","M2","9816","PR","9912","R2","9914","S1","10636","D1","10665","I1","10718","S2","10729","I2","13502","D2","14008","G1","14014","G2","14020","M3","14097","I1","16302","I2","19227"]},{t:175272,l:1,ct:1485861583752,a:["https%253A%252F%252Fportal.office.com%252FSuiteServiceProxy.aspx%253Fupn%253Dpricen%252540njpenterprises.com%2526suiteServiceReturnUrl%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fnjpenterprises.sharepoint.com%25252Fsites%25252Fdev%25252Fspfx%25252F_layouts%25252F15%25252Fworkbench.aspx%2526returnUrl%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fnjpenterprises.sharepoint.com%25252Fsites%25252Fdev%25252Fspfx%25252F_layouts%25252F15%25252Fworkbench.aspx"]},{t:421422,l:6,ct:1485861583763,a:["Cannot%2520access%2520https%253A%252F%252Fportal.office.com%252FSuiteServiceProxy.aspx%253Fupn%253Dpricen%252540njpenterprises.com%2526suiteServiceReturnUrl%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fnjpenterprises.sharepoint.com%25252Fsites%25252Fdev%25252Fspfx%25252F_layouts%25252F15%25252Fworkbench.aspx%2526returnUrl%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fnjpenterprises.sharepoint.com%25252Fsites%25252Fdev%25252Fspfx%25252F_layouts%25252F15%25252Fworkbench.aspx"]},{t:410681,l:4,ct:1485861583765,a:["https%253A%252F%252Fportal.office.com%252Fapi%252Fmyapps%252FGetAllApps","GET"]},{t:421432,l:1,ct:1485861583891,a:["0"]},{t:175261,l:1,ct:1485861598529,a:["dd677c9b-d582-4b9b-b380-45349acac10e"]}],a:["s","Sharepoint","shpid","1485861564314","shsid","af21b00a-be43-441e-a6b2-02828b189b84","u","3b756550-4641-468c-9e77-bd03f923f959","t","4e7056d6-0830-41be-a136-93b24c588169","p","10037FFE8190ABEB","c","false","sid","b7a308bf-338a-4061-a7fb-c71931e07a34"]}&cb=1485861628532
> HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the
> requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier). GET -
> https://clientlog.portal.office.com/l.l/?d={m:[{t:408369,l:1,ct:1485861571727,a:["O365SuiteService%252Fapi%252FAppLauncherCustomization%252FUser%252FAppsCustomizationDataTEST"]},{t:171063,l:1,ct:1485861564314,a:["P1","5098","PL","9125","CM1","8985","CM2","8986","C1","9750","C2","9767","M_C","1","M_L","Mouse","SC1","9213","RC1","9439","RC2","9523","R1","9807","M2","9816","PR","9912","R2","9914","S1","10636","D1","10665","I1","10718","S2","10729","I2","13502","D2","14008","G1","14014","G2","14020","M3","14097","I1","16302","I2","19227"]},{t:175272,l:1,ct:1485861583752,a:["https%253A%252F%252Fportal.office.com%252FSuiteServiceProxy.aspx%253Fupn%253Dpricen%252540njpenterprises.com%2526suiteServiceReturnUrl%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fnjpenterprises.sharepoint.com%25252Fsites%25252Fdev%25252Fspfx%25252F_layouts%25252F15%25252Fworkbench.aspx%2526returnUrl%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fnjpenterprises.sharepoint.com%25252Fsites%25252Fdev%25252Fspfx%25252F_layouts%25252F15%25252Fworkbench.aspx"]},{t:421422,l:6,ct:1485861583763,a:["Cannot%2520access%2520https%253A%252F%252Fportal.office.com%252FSuiteServiceProxy.aspx%253Fupn%253Dpricen%252540njpenterprises.com%2526suiteServiceReturnUrl%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fnjpenterprises.sharepoint.com%25252Fsites%25252Fdev%25252Fspfx%25252F_layouts%25252F15%25252Fworkbench.aspx%2526returnUrl%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fnjpenterprises.sharepoint.com%25252Fsites%25252Fdev%25252Fspfx%25252F_layouts%25252F15%25252Fworkbench.aspx"]},{t:410681,l:4,ct:1485861583765,a:["https%253A%252F%252Fportal.office.com%252Fapi%252Fmyapps%252FGetAllApps","GET"]},{t:421432,l:1,ct:1485861583891,a:["0"]},{t:175261,l:1,ct:1485861598529,a:["dd677c9b-d582-4b9b-b380-45349acac10e"]}],a:["s","Sharepoint","shpid","1485861564314","shsid","af21b00a-be43-441e-a6b2-02828b189b84","u","3b756550-4641-468c-9e77-bd03f923f959","t","4e7056d6-0830-41be-a136-93b24c588169","p","10037FFE8190ABEB","c","false","sid","b7a308bf-338a-4061-a7fb-c71931e07a34"]}&cb=1485861628532
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ian Clanton-Thuon (MSFT) showed me the fix saying : delete the `<homedir>/.gcb-serve-data` directory and running `gulp trust-dev-cert` again.  This worked !  The existing directory was created way back in February 2016 before SPFx came onstream.

Comment: What is the location of `.gcb-serve-data`? Actually I did not find the directory under the web part solution directory. Can you please post the actual path? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 7):

Run the below command to install the certificate, note that the certification error in the local workbench also disappears after this.

`gulp trust-dev-cert`

After this, you can run gulp serve to again see the local workbench and then launch the Office 365 tenant site to see if your locally developed webpart is available to be added on the workbench.aspx.

Comment: Tried this but 1) I still get the certificate error on the local workbench and 2) my locally developed webpart still does not appear on the list of webparts I can add.

Comment: Is it visible on the the local workbench page, `temp/workbench.html` ? Try adding the webpart on this page.  Also ensure that latest npm package is installed. The version should be 0.4.1 , to install run `npm i -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@latest` this command

Comment: Yes it is visible on my local workbench (temp/workbench.html).  Version 0.4.1 is installed. Still does not work on any of my tenancies.

Comment: Are you on a dev tenant or a tenant where first release is enabled (not for specific users, but for everyone) ? At my end, I use the `https://sitecollectionurl/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx` to add webpart, is that page available in your tenant ?

Comment: I have tried both - yes that page is available on both tenancies

Comment: I can get it to work in Chrome if I load this first and allowing unsafe scripts -> https://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js

Comment: I can now get it to work in IE11 again by loading https://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js first and allowing unsafe scripts - not an ideal solution

Comment: This is very strange. Are you using admin account to run gulp ? Add the user to admin group and run `gulp trust-dev-cert`. Also, was there any error when you tried that command previously ?

Comment: Yes I am using an admin account to run gulp trust-dev-cert.  Have a look at the answer to see the output from IE Debugger.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the Edge browser, try Chrome. Does not work in Edge in my experience.

Comment: I had the same issue, deleted `.gcb-serve-data` and re-ran `gulp trust-dev-cert` but I still get `Your web part will not appear in the toolbox. Please make sure "gulp serve" is running in a web part project. Please refresh the page once "gulp serve" is running.` in Edge. Works as expected in Chrome however.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else struggling to find the .gcb-serve-data folder, an example path is...

C:/Users/PCOX/.gcb-serve-data i.e. the same route as wehre the documents, music and downloads libraries are, its also a hidden folder.

Answer (score 0):

Copying the same comment as above as I it helped me, wasn't able to upvote it:

For anyone else struggling to find the `.gcb-serve-data` folder, an example path is:

```
C:/Users/{username}/.gcb-serve-data
```

- Go to `cmd` & change directory to: `cd C:/Users/{username}`
- Then next command: `del C:/Users/{username}/.gcb-serve-data`
- After that try `gulp trust-dev-cert` again

Answer (score 0):

if the developer certificate already trusted by the command `gulp trust-dev-cert` then open this URL in new tab

```
https://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js
```

and try to re-run gulp serve